# How do I keep and append placeholder text into the selected value in React Select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Let's say I have a React Select with a placeholder ('Selected Value: '), and I want to keep the placeholder and append it into the selected value so that it looks something like ('Selected Value: 1'). Is there any way to do it?

```
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { value: 1, label: 1 },
    { value: 2, label: 2 },
    { value: 3, label: 3 },
    { value: 4, label: 4 }
  ];
  const placeholder = "Selected Value: ";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={options} placeholder={placeholder} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-chatterjee-pjol2d?file=/src/App.js:23-385

EDIT: Sorry, forget to mention, I do not want the placeholder to directly be in the labels of the options

Comment: Add Label yourself above of select. I do not get any property for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can accept my answer

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectBoxValue, setSelectBoxValue] = useState('')
  const options = [
    { value: 1, label: 1 },
    { value: 2, label: 2 },
    { value: 3, label: 3 },
    { value: 4, label: 4 }
  ];
  const placeholder = `Selected Value: ${selectBoxValue}`;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select 
      options={options} 
      placeholder={placeholder} 
      value={placeholder}
      onChange={(event) => setSelectBoxValue(event.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It kinda works, but is there anyway that I can style the selected value and placeholder differently? (IE: grey color for 'Selected Value: ', blue color for '1')

Answer (score 1):

just use these options:

```
const options = [
    { value: 1, label: 'Selected Value: 1' },
    { value: 2, label: 'Selected Value: 2' },
    { value: 3, label: 'Selected Value: 3' },
    { value: 4, label: 'Selected Value: 4' }
  ];
```

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention, I do not want the placeholder to directly be in the labels of the options

Answer (score 1):

Read https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/

```
<Select
  value={personName}
  onChange={handleChange}
  renderValue={(selected) => {
  if (selected.length === 0) {
       return <em>Placeholder</em>;
  }
   return 'placeholder '+selected;
  }}
 >
```

Possible two solutions:

1. You can use renderValue to render what you want.
2. You can use state and pass the value as value props. On handleChange you can change the state of value.
   it should work.